# How to identify if uploaded excel file is same as that is downloaded?

Tags: java, excel, upload, download, jxl

I am developing excel download & upload functionality using Java.

I have a link on my screen through which, user will download an excel.

I provide functionality to upload the excel. But, while uploading, I want restrict user to upload only that excel file which is downloaded to maintain security.

How will I be able to do that ?

I am using JXL API for Java.

**EDIT:**
User will download the file, which will have all protected cells.

User will change the details in it and then re-upload it.

User may copy the content of the excel and save in another excel file and then add some junk data in it which may come across some security concerns.

To avoid it while uploading the file, I want to identify if the file is same as that is downloaded.

Comment: Why would you do that?! If you already have that file on your server, why would you like to be able to reupload it?

Comment: just check the file name , make an ajax call , make sure the filename follows your algorithm , and then allow user to upload

Comment: Just checking file name won't suffice, User may create another excel file with same name.

Comment: if you want the user to download the file, make changes to it and upload a new version, then you could try adding a watermark into the file, or another kind of unique ID.

Comment: How are you preventing them from "add[ing] some junk data" to the file you send them?

Comment: @EricStein: Blocking the cells.

Comment: @victorantunes: Watermark is possible using jxl api ?

Comment: @Sarang Watermarking is just an idea. It could probably also work by using a randomly-generated unique numeric ID.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to add an unique ID somewhere inside the file and lock those cells from editing.

You could check this tutorial on how to [Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-HA010096837.aspx)

Also, you can compare the files' creation date timestamps and check if they're the same.

Comment: File creation date timestamps can be spoofed. If they copy the contents of the sheet, they get the hidden cell. They don't even need to know that it's there.

Comment: Does excel not have an option to disable content copy?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The user has everything. If they are a dedicated attacker, they can hack the password or manually copy data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do what you want. The user will have access to everything you give them. If they are attacking you, they can use that to spoof that the file is the same. You need to do data validation on what comes in from the user, just like any other time you ask the user for data.

Probably the closest you can get is to check that every locked cell is still locked with the same password. There's still no guarantee that they haven't hacked your password, though, and once you're looking at every cell anyway, you may as well validate the value instead of the lock.

Answer (score 0):

1. Protect sheet( or required cells) with a password.
2. On upload verify the password.
3. Store the password in property files or in some secured location.

I have resolved my issue using Apache POI lib and "validateSheetPassword(pwd)" method.